# How to get max Value in PowerBI for a measure for each category

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-datasource

i am making a powerbi report which should give me the category having maximum value of defect (not total)

This is my dataset
[PowerBI Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yYU4N.png)

I am trying to use the following DAX formula

```
NO 1 Defect = LOOKUPVALUE('Camera Data'[Attribute],'Camera Data'[Value],MAX('Camera Data'[Value]))
```

And i am using a card to display the category of max value. This works fine till the time i have a single max value. the moment it becomes more than 1 then it is giving error

```
Multiple values supplied where only 1 value was expected
```

All i want is only the first of that max value category should be displayed on the card. How can i do it?

PS: to extract data from the image you can use this site https://extracttable.com/ this would work for free and 1 image will be easily converted to dataset.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple way to get the Attribute correpsonding to the maximum value is to use CALCULATE to apply a filter context on the rows with the maximum value and then to use MAX() or MIN() to get only one value in case of ties

```
NO 1 Defect = 
VAR MaxValue = MAX( 'Camera Data'[Value] )
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    MAX('Camera Data'[Attribute]),
    'Camera Data'[Value] = MaxValue
)
```

If all Attributes are to be displayed in case of ties, then the CONCATENATEX() function can be used

```
NO 1 Defect List = 
VAR MaxValue = MAX( 'Camera Data'[Value] )
RETURN
CALCULATE(
    CONCATENATEX('Camera Data', 'Camera Data'[Attribute], ", " ),
    'Camera Data'[Value] = MaxValue
)
```

In case the "Total Count" rows that appear in your image are actual rows to be excluded, an alternative definition for MaxValue variable should be used

```
VAR MaxValue = CALCULATE(
                    MAX( 'Camera Data'[Value] ), 
                    'Camera Data'[Attribute] <> "Total Count"
               )
```